# Shopify GraphQL "cartLinesAdd" API

Tags: graphql, postman, shopify, storefront

[image: I am trying to add products to my cart using this API. But in response, it says invalid ID]

When I hit this Shopify GraphQL "cartLinesAdd" API to add product to my shopping cart, in response it says invalid ID. So, can anyone please help me to find out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The [cart docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/cart/manage) on Shopify seem to show they want "merchandiseId" to start with "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/" so I guess you should replace yours with the same value, but this at the front of it.